# Flatten nested data frames in weird JSON format in R

Tags: r, json

Hi I am fairly new to JSON and R but I have read numerous posts and cannot find an answer to my issue.
I have JSON data with multiple nested data frames in a format that I have not seen anywhere on here. This is an example of how it is coming through with both the field_name and field_value as variables.

```
 ..$ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ field_name : chr  "Staff Type" "Appointment ID"
  .. ..$ field_value: chr  "TEACHING" ""
  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ field_name : chr  "Staff Type" "Appointment ID"
  .. ..$ field_value: chr  "SENIOR STAFF (ACADEMIC)" ""
```

I have tried flatten() and various unnest, unlist but it still appears as
'list(field_name = c("Staff Type", "Appointment ID"), field_val...'

I have seem a post derived from this data set and this is more the format I would expect.

```
..$ stats:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
.. ..$ speed : num  55 34
.. ..$ weight: num  67 24
.. ..$ drift : num  35 32
```

Can anyone help? I have loads of these fields :-(
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read and share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could try `do.call("rbind", data_json)`, where `data_json` is the data you read from the JSON file.

Comment: Hi Vincent thanks but that didn't work, if I run it on the field with list(field_name = c("Staff Type", "Appointment ID"), field_val.. then it outputs 

        field_name             field_value
1       Staff Type                      FT
2   Appointment ID           TestuserFT011
3       Staff Type                      FT
4   Appointment ID           TestuserFT011
5       Staff Type                      PT

I need field_name as the variable name and field_value as the value. Is the JSON format bad/unnusual? Thanks